# What is good CSS / HTML / SVG / Javascript to do a loop image for score 0 to 10? (need to work on IE 7 and other common browsers)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

To do an image like this:

[image]

It has to support a score from 0.0 to 10.0, and the solid color is painted accordingly -- for 1.0, it is 36 degree, for 9.0, it is 360 x 0.9 = 324 degree.

Is there a good way to do it just using HTML / CSS / SVG / Javascript?  The requirement is that it needs to work on IE 7 and up, FF, Chrome, and Safari. **(Update: Or, do it for IE 8 and up, and for IE 7, just fall back to a solid color loop)**

---

I was thinking of using a solid loop (1 image), plus 20 images with alpha transparencies to cover up the solid loop, so that a granularity of 0.5 (such as 4.0, 4.5, 5.0) are all covered, but the downside is that there are 21 images total (can put into a sprite, but still quite large).

Comment: IE7 will handle the alpha transparencies poorly, you'd be better off using a solid color that is that pale orange instead of using alpha.

Comment: If you need IE7 support, **SVG is completely out of the question**.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks. what if only for IE 8 and up, and fall back to solid color loop for IE 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This paragraph:

> I was thinking of using a solid loop
>   (1 image), plus 20 images with alpha
>   transparencies to cover up the solid
>   loop, so that a granularity of 0.5
>   (such as 4.0, 4.5, 5.0) are all
>   covered, but the downside is that
>   there are 21 images total (can put
>   into a sprite, but still quite large).

sounds like a lot of work :)

Instead, I might be tempted to use [**Raphaël**](http://raphaeljs.com/) for this.

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox
>   3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Here's a demo that looks vaguely like your image, and has animated concentric circles:

http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) JS library? Take a look at their examples, they're pretty impressive.

Comment: yes, impressive indeed.  I also tried Protovis... but for some reason its Polar Clock is not working on IE 8 running on IE 7 Compat Mode on the Virtual PC using VirtualBox... but Raphael's Polar Clock is running fine

Answer (score 1):

**[Scalable Vector Graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) and [Vector Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vml)**

Comment: using which, and not for IE 7 but just IE 8 and up?

Comment: SVG for gecko, webkit, opera; VML for IEs (5+)